# The meaning of 'permanent mate'

Tags: meaning

That word is from a newspaper article.
-Men without work find it hard to attract a permanent mate.

What is the meaning of permanent mate?
Is it like a forever friend? or... a life partner?

Comment: Have you looked up the word "[mate](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mate_1)"? Which definition do you think applies here?

Comment: @Cat - I think the O.P. probably _did_ look up "mate," given the two options suggested in the question. Your link lists _friend_ (Def. 2), as well as _spouse_ (Def. 4). This question may not quote a dictionary definition, but I see evidence of prior research here.

Comment: I am guessing that there is other context around the quote that indicates which definition to use.

Comment: @user3169: No, there's more than enough context here to tell which one is meant.

Answer (score 2):

*Mate* in this context means *husband/wife* (i.e. spouse) or a similar relationship.  A life partner could be considered a mate.  It's more intimate than a friend for sure, especially when a mate is described as permanent.

*Mate* can be used in reference to animals (i.e. *there is a duck swimming with his mate*), but is not really a derogatory or condescending term typically when applied to people.  I believe the term is being used here because the speaker/writer might talking about non-traditional relationships, i.e. people who aren't married for whatever reason, but would be equivalently committed to each other.

Consider that another meaning of *mate* is *to form a pair* (e.g. *I mated the pair of socks*), and this is sort of what is implied, that two people are together because they are a match.

*Mate* can also two or more that have a close bond (not necessarily sexual) - either due to circumstances or other, but usually this will be qualified with an immediate preceding modifier: *office mate*, *car mate*, etc.  Some very common expressions of this can be spelled as one word: *soulmate*, *cellmate*, *playmate*.